# Translating a Euclidean proof to hyperbolic language..

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

User HyperLuminal asked for help to prove the following statement:

> [Connecting the feet of the altitudes of a given triangle, we obtain another triangle for with the altitudes of the original triangle are angle bisectors of the new triangle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309946/homework-geometry-triangle-proof-help-high-school)

User @Alexey Burdin gave nice answer. Alexey's answer is based on a fact true only in **Euclidean geometry**. He had a quadrangle with two opposite right angles and used the fact that this quadrangle has a special circum circle centered at the altitude point of the triangle of the OP... (Pls. see his answer.)

> **My claim is** that the OP's claim is true in the **hyperbolic geometry** as well. However I cannot prove this statement. My main problem is that I cannot detach myself from the Burdin solution.

Help needed either to falsify my claim or to prove it.

Comment: Thanks. Very pleased for such great attention. Other approaches I could think of: (sorry, all Euclidean, but also I'm not very familiar with hyperbolic geometry though) vectors, $\sin$es, Euler line. I'd also try to prove/counterexample to the main idea of that solution: do these mentioned $4$ points ought to be concyclic (or how do we say in hyperbolic geometry) and is it needed and/or suffice to the mentioned angles to be equal. In other words, to break that solution from the inside. I'd try some kind of coordinates also, if I knew hyperbolical ones :) Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Alexy Burdin: Try to make up an Euclidean proof that does not use similarity and/or Thales' theorem. Do not refer to parallelism. So try to get a Euclidean proof which is independent from the axiom of parallelism.

Comment: @Alexey Burdin: I encourage you to try to prove the statement with parallelism independent tools. We still need your contr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a coordinate proof using the Poincaré disk model (identified with the unit circle).

[image]

Take $A = (p,0)$, $B=(q,0)$, $C=(0,r)$ (for non-zero $p$, $q$, $r$), so that the origin is the foot of the altitude from $C$. Inverting $B$ in the unit circle naturally gives $B^\prime = (q^{-1},0)$, which allow us to find the equation of the circle (representing the hyperbolic line) through $B$ and $C$: 
$$\bigcirc{B^\prime BC}:\quad x^2+y^2 - 2x \dot{q} - 2y \dot{r} + 1 = 0$$
where $\dot{q} := \frac12(q+q^{-1})$ and $\dot{r} = \frac12(r+r^{-1})$.

Inverting $A$ in the unit circle to get $A^\prime$, and inverting $A$ in $\bigcirc{B^\prime BC}$ to get $A^{\prime\prime}$ gives the equation for the circle representing the altitude from $A$:

$$\bigcirc A^\prime AA^{\prime\prime}:\quad 
x^2+y^2 - 2 x \dot{p} \dot{r} + 2 y \frac{ \dot{p} \dot{q} - 1 }{\dot{r}} + 1$$

The foot of that altitude, $D$, is the intersection the two circles. Foot $E$ of the altitude from $B$ is another such intersection. Rather than solve the messy quadratics, let's remind ourselves that we're interested in comparing $\angle DOB$ and $\angle EOA$. Then, because hyperbolic lines through $O$ are represented by Euclidean lines, so that $D = (d, d m)$ for some slope $m$, we can substitute these coordinates into the two equations above; eliminating $d$, we get
$$m = - \frac{(p - q) (1 - p q) \dot{r}}{
2 p q \left( \dot{p} \dot{q} + \ddot{r}^2 \right)} \tag{$\star$}$$

where $\ddot{r} := \frac12(r-r^{-1})$.

Formula ($\star$) is *anti-symmetric* in $p$ and $q$ (equivalently, this analysis is anti-symmetric in $A$ and $B$): switching the parameters only changes the sign of the value. Consequently, the angle formed by (Euclidean *or* hyperbolic) lines $\overline{OD}$ and $\overline{OE}$ is bisected by $\overline{OC}$ (here, the $y$-axis). $\square$

---

**Notes.** Recall that in the Poincaré model, Euclidean distance $d$ from the origin represents hyperbolic distance $d^\star = \log\frac{1+d}{1-d}$, so that 
$$d = \frac{\exp d^\star - 1}{\exp d^\star + 1} =\tanh\frac{d^\star}{2} \qquad \dot{d} = \coth d^\star \qquad \ddot{d} = -\operatorname{csch} d^\star$$

Therefore, we can ultimately write ($\star$) as
$$m = \frac{\sinh(p^\star - q^\star)\;\sinh 2r^\star}{2(\;\sinh p^\star \sinh q^\star + \cosh p^\star \cosh q^\star \sinh^2 r^\star\;)} \tag{$\star\star$}$$
where $p^\star := |OA|$, $q^\star := |OB|$, $r^\star := |OC|$ are  *hyperbolic* lengths of elements in hyperbolic $\triangle ABC$. (We assign opposite signs to $p^\star$ and $q^\star$ if they are on opposite sides of $O$, and matching signs if they're on the same side of $O$.) Expressing $(\star\star)$ in terms of the sides and angles of $\triangle ABC$ is left as an exercise for the reader. (As a start: $p^\star - q^\star = |AB|$. Also, as a sanity check: the formula must reduce to $\tan C$ in the "infinitesimal case", since $\angle AOE = \angle BOD = \angle C$ in a Euclidean triangle.)

Comment: Thx. I am studying the proof. (To be honest my dream proof is an absolute proof, that is, a proof that can be told to people who know nothing about hyperbolic geometry and would understand the statement and the proof as a Euclidean theorem.)

Comment: @zoli: An absolute proof would indeed be preferable. I'll note this: When the three altitudes concur at a point (the orthocenter), we can make essentially-identical arguments in Euclidean and hyperbolic geometry using corresponding versions of Ceva's Theorem. Unfortunately, not all hyperbolic triangles have an orthocenter. (If we restrict ourselves to *acute* triangles, then they do.)

Comment: But the existence of the absolute ortho-triangle has nothing to do with the existence of a common point of the altitude lines. There may still exist an "essentially different" absolute proof. Philosophically: When can we say that an absolute proof does not exist?

Comment: @zoli: *"But the existence of the absolute ortho-triangle has nothing to do with the existence of a common point of the altitude lines."* Quite correct, and I wasn't suggesting otherwise. I was simply pointing out that, when there *is* such a point, there's a somewhat-unified (if not quite "absolute") approach to a proof. This may (or may not) provide hope of an absolute proof in the general case.

Comment: Think of common perpendicular to the altitude line and to the sides of the orth triangle. This common perp exists even under Eu circumstancies, then, of course, the orig triangle is flat.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your conjecture is true in hyperbolic geometry.

Here is a construction to test and play around with it (and inspire you for a proof or to find an counterexample)

Remember ONE counter example is enough to disprove your conjecture, but no  amount of examples is enough to prove your conjecture (for proof you just  need other ways)

It is a quite fiddely construction. (be warned)

Best way is to construct it in the Beltrami klein model of hyperbolic geometry (see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami%E2%80%93Klein_model )

The wikipedia page gives all you the construcions you need to make a countermodel. ( I resently added them :)

- Start with an triangle
- Find the polars of the sides
- Draw lines between the vertices of the triangle and the poles of the opposite sides
- Construct the altitude triangle
- Construct  the angle bisectors (again see the wikipedia page)
  and check if they do align

Good luck

EDITED

first I thought I had  found a counter example, but then reconcidering maybe I made a mistake somewhere in my construction (did i not say it was fiddely ? , see comments)

Comment: Check the construction carefully again. I am attaching here a link to my construction:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/YEaa3.png

Comment: Your  construction looks correct but do make lines of the altitudes instead of rays, i did reconstruct it and now they are the same line. I corrected my answer. What is now if you are critical no answer at all, but still i hope helpful to find a proof, so i will leave it.